# BIRT Using Date parameter in script

Tags: javascript, birt

I am using BIRT and am trying to modify the text on a chart based on an end date report parameter, which I've assigned a default value and of course, Date datatype. SQL queries also use this parameter. To test passing of value, I write the below script.

```
function beforeDrawLegendItem( lerh, bounds, icsc )
{
    var endDate = new Date(params["rptEndDate"].value);
}
```

However, when I try to preview the chart, it is blank, indicating that there is something wrong with my script. When I comment out the var endDate line, it renders as normal. I've tried other ways to get the value like:

```
var endDate = new Date();
```

Which works, but when I try to assign the parameter value:

```
endDate = params["rptEndDate"].value;
```

It fails again. Removing the .value part also fails. Also fails when I try to use reportContext to get the parameter value. According to other sources my script should be correct. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the specifity of the chart engine: "params" object is not made available in chart scripts, use "getParameterValue" instead. It will work like this:

```
function beforeDrawLegendItem( lerh, bounds, icsc )
{
    var endDate = new Date(getParameterValue("rptEndDate"));
}
```

Comment: I've found a solution myself which seems similar to what you recommended:  `icsc.getExternalContext().getScriptable().getParameterValue("rptEndDate")`

Comment: Yes it is the same, the prefix icsc.getExternalContext().getScriptable() is not required anymore unless we use a quite old BIRT version

Answer (score 0):

The Previewer tends to offer less then optimally formated or fully functional design.  Open the report in the format/tool that will be used in the final delivery for true testing durring design.  Personally I have Apache on my test server and do all of my preview testing as a web page.